# css inline-block element positioning

Tags: css

I would like to create a webpage for a simple chat, so one big frame for message, a smarter frame (at the right side) for a user list and a line where user can compose message below the second first frame.

I have created 3 frames without any problem but my problem is that I can't find how to make the `contactbox` frame take the entire left space. If I put width in % it is under the message frame. Can anyone help me please?

HTML

```
<div id="content">
<section id="mainframe">
    <article id="messagebox">
        <p>User1 : Message 1</p>
        <p>User1 : Message 2</p>
    </article>
    <aside id="contactbox">
        <p>User1</p>
    </aside>
    <aside id="composebox">
        <p>I'll write my message here</p>
    </aside>
</section>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#mainframe{
    border: 1px solid white;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

#mainframe p{
    margin: 0;
}

#mainframe #messagebox{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 85%;
    min-width: 250px;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    min-height: 500px;
}

#mainframe #contactbox{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15%;
    min-width: 150px;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 500px;
    text-align: right;
}

#mainframe #composebox{
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 400px;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Here's a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bqw7wway/)** with some colour added to the containers so it's easier to see what's wrong.

Comment: please make a fiddle so that it is easier for us to see the problem in action

Comment: @Anubhav everything you need to make a fiddle is there, so just copy and paste it

Comment: @Tanner I agree also.. but at the same time do we really have to copy and paste and add it on fiddle? sounds like extra work for us :)...or im just lazy.

Comment: took me all of 10 seconds to create this: http://jsfiddle.net/bqw7wway/, compared to the fact the OP hasn't responded to the request yet. You can ask the question and wait or just go ahead and do it if everything is there and you want to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things make the contactbox break to the next line:

1. By default, a content box model is used for sizing. That means, `width` specifies the width available for the actual content and the padding and border are added to it. So, your `#messagebox` actually is 85% + 2px wide. You can fix this by declaring `box-sizing: border-box;` for `#messagebox` and `#contactbox`, so that the browser uses the declared `width` for the entire size of the box.
2. There are white-spaces between the two boxes, which add additional space. An easy fix is commenting them out.

Here is a fiddle, that should work as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/k193m66e/

If you care for old browsers, which don't support `box-sizing`, you could also try a `float` based layout.

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much. It is exactly what i'm looking for. Just one more question, write my code each line under the previous line is bad for element positionning?

Comment: It is bad for the way you're doing element positioning. In general, it is good practice for readability. But you can try to avoid this white-space problem with one of the floating solutions posted by others.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place elements side-by-side on a webpage, it helps to learn about [the float property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp). By applying this property, you can tell an element to "float" to the right or left of a page. Other content will wrap around it. I've given a simple example below, in which your `messagebox` takes a column filling 85% of the page on the left, your `contactbox` takes a column filling 15% on the right, and the `composebox` fill 100% of the page beneath both.

HTML is unchanged, here is the CSS:

```
#messagebox {
    float:left;
    width:85%;
}
#contactbox {
    float:right;
    width:15%;
}
#composebox {
    clear:both;
}
```

You can see a live demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/snLgrjeq/). I've added filler text so that you can see how the columns wrap properly when filled with content.

The `clear:both` property basically says "don't display this until after the floated elements".

Comment: thank you but i read that this is better to use inline-block instead floating system. I've done it right with float but on multiple website it say that float is the old system and it is more powerfull to place elements with inline-block. Isn't right?

Comment: i missed that part of your question, so i suppose i didn't really answer your question.

Comment: that said, i prefer float, if only because it's supported universally.

Comment: ok, i've heard that most of developpers use float, is there any other advantage for me to use float instead inline-block?

Comment: float also changes how children see the attributes of a floated parent. in some senses, it's as if a floated element is removed from the DOM: to its children, it appears to have a size of 0px and a few other things. i'm not sure about the technical details.

Comment: that's a big reason people might be trying to move away from float, but in some cases (probably with some AJAX scripting), it might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Although question is answered, still you can also try this. Its a bit more simpler solution.

**CSS**

```
#contactbox
{
width:20%;
float:left;
}
#mainframe
{
width:80%;
float:left;
min-height:500px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="mainframe">
    <p>User1 : Message 1</p>
    <p>User1 : Message 2</p>
</div>
<div id="contactbox">
    <p>User1</p>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div id="composebox">
I'll write my message here.
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t1rk5fsf/)**